# Can't run PHP scripts from command line

Tags: php, apache, setup-deployment

I had php 5.3 installed with apache 2.2
I just added php 5.57 x64 with apache 2.4 x64
both setups seem to be working fine in parallel when pulling php pages through browsers
can't run php pages/scripts from command line using the new php 5.57 executable
(I cd to the directory `c:\php55` then run the command: `php -f c:\... path` to template in htdocs)
same php pages/scripts run just fine with 5.3 php executable using same exact command
same php pages/scripts run just fine through browsers using the new php 5.57 executable (configured on port 8080)

I'm on windows 2008 r2

any idea folks?

Comment: Check the path environment variable

Comment: Please elaborate on *can't run*. What makes you think that you *can't run PHP scripts from command line*? Any error messages? If so, which ones?

Comment: No error. When I click enter, almost immediately I get the cursor back but nothing happens. I checked apache error log, apache access log, php error log and saw nothing. In addition I added the php directory to the PATH env. variable list

Answer (score 0):

You should use absolute path. For example

```
c:\php55\php.exe c:\htdosc\script.php
```

Also check waht php executable file is in folder c:\php55 May be it in c:\php55\bin

Comment: I checked the executable using php -v and found that when ever I use 5.57 version, the script doesn't run. I used the absolute path indeed just like you list it.